# How can I draw this graph in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart, linegraph

How can I draw such a graph using Swing? I have used a [`JFreeChart`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) library, but I don't know how can I draw such a line graph using that library?

[image: graph]

```
import org.jfree.chart.*;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.data.xy.*;

public class DrawGraph{

public void drawGraph(int[][] drawPoints) {
  XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Average Weight");
  for(int i=0;i<drawPoints.length;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<=1;j+=2){
        if(drawPoints[i][j]!=0){
            series.add(bla...bla...bla...);
        }
    }
  }

  XYDataset xyDataset = new XYSeriesCollection(series);
  JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart
  ("XYLine Chart using JFreeChart", "Age", "Weight",
 xyDataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
  ChartFrame frame1=new ChartFrame("XYLine Chart",chart);
  frame1.setVisible(true);
  frame1.setSize(300,300);
  }

}
```

I have drawn graph using this but isn't working...

Comment: A picture paints a thousand words.  What does ***your*** graph look like?

Comment: @AndrewThompson: i have given a link for the graph... at the top or click [here](http://i.imgur.com/ahyiQ.jpg)

Comment: So you want to draw a picture like the one at the top or is the top one the one you've drawn?

Comment: i want to draw a picture like the top. that is : [http://i.imgur.com/ahyiQ.jpg]

Comment: *"i have given a link for the graph"*  Yes, I saw it before making my comment, noi need for the 2nd & 3rd link to the **same** image.  But there are **2 graphs involved** 1) the one you want 2) the one you have.  Show us ***what you have!***

Comment: @AndrewThompson :sorry man, i doesn't mean like that, i thought you might not have notice that, that's why i given that link, btw, how can i draw as a link suggest from what i have done? :)

Comment: *"how can i draw as a link suggest from what i have done?"* What?  That sentence makes no sense to me.  Are you still referring to the 'what I have' image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're having trouble constructing a dataset. You can use a method like that shown below with either `ChartFactory.createXYAreaChart()` or `ChartFactory.createXYLineChart()`.

```
private static XYDataset createDataset() {
    XYSeriesCollection result = new XYSeriesCollection();
    XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Test");
    series.add(0, 2);
    // more points here
    series.add(10, 10);
    result.addSeries(series);
    return result;
}
```

See also these [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:200987%20%5Bjfreechart%5D%20fill&submit=search).

As an aside, it's not clear what's important in you picture, and I can't make sense of the unordered axis at the top. In my opinion, the better question is not *How do I make this graph?* but rather *How can I best display this data?*

Answer (score 0):

http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/jung/wiki/JUNGManual

Use JUNG instead. Its easy and written in java.